# how to add query on relational data in laravel

Tags: laravel

my query is

```
$payment_history=User::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
->orWhere('email','like','%'.$search.'%')
->with(['payment_history'=>function($query,$request){
                $query->whereBetween('date', array($request->from, $request->to))
                      ->orderBy('id','Desc');
}])
->paginate(30);
```

I am getting this erorr:

`Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\Payment\PaymentController::App\Http\Controllers\Payment\{closure}(), called in /var/www/html/panel/vendor/laravel/fr ▶`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass `$request` as function argument like that `function($query,$request)`. You need to use it `function($query) use ($request)`

```
$payment_history = User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->with(['payment_history' => function($query) use ($request){
        $query->whereBetween('date', array($request->from, $request->to))
              ->orderBy('id', 'Desc');
    }])->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding your closure error is caused by the second paramenter - your use of the `$request` as second paramenter is wrong..

instead of

```
function($query,$request)
```

rather it should be

```
function($query) use($request)
```

not the way u did it..

```
$payment_history=User::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
->orWhere('email','like','%'.$search.'%')
->with(
     ['payment_history'=>function($query) use($request){
         $query->whereBetween('date', array($request->from, $request->to))
         ->orderBy('id','Desc');
  }]
)
->paginate(30);
```